# Get date and time in UTC format in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

How can I get a datetime in UTC time in this format ('2002-05-30T09:30:10Z') in C++?
This is the function I have made.

```
void settime(){
      // Current date/time based on current system
  time_t now = time(0);
   
  // Convert now to tm struct for local timezone
  tm* localtm = localtime(&now);
  cout << "The local date and time is: " << asctime(localtm) << endl;

  // Convert now to tm struct for UTC
  tm* gmtm = gmtime(&now);
  if (gmtm != NULL) {
     cout << "The UTC date and time is: " << asctime(gmtm) << endl;
  }
  else {
    cerr << "Failed to get the UTC date and time" << endl;
  
  } 
}
```

This function print in this format 'The UTC date and time is: Mon Oct 12 18:56:59 2020' right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [free, open-source, header-only preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    namespace cr = std::chrono;
    std::cout << date::format("%FT%TZ", cr::floor<cr::seconds>(cr::system_clock::now())) << '\n';
}
```

This will easily port to C++20 by:

- Drop `#include "date/date.h"`
- Change `date::format` to `std::format`
- Change `"%FT%TZ"` to `"{:%FT%TZ}"`

Comment: When I'm using std::format it gives me an error that namespace std has no member format.

Comment: For now you will have to use the [free, open-source, header-only preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  Vendors are still working on implementing C++20.

Comment: Now when I'm using date::format I'm getting this error 'C++ name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name'

Comment: I can help if you show the _first_ error in its entirety.

Comment: Not "{%FT%TZ}" but"{:%FT%TZ}"